# Declension of cвитер

Tags: орфография

While studying I encountered this word 'cвитер' and then I wondered why there were two forms of the plural for all the declensions.

[image: declensions]

Does anyone know if this is from the old or the new orthography, which plural form is spoken more currently and more commonly?

Maybe there is simply a difference seen in intonation and pronunciation.

Comment: Did you read the footnote to the table?

Comment: Мы говорим не «штОрмы», а «штормА» —
Слова выходят коротки и смачны.
«ВетрА» — не «ветрЫ» — сводят нас с ума,
Из палуб выкорчёвывая мачты.(с) В.Высоцкий

Comment: Дело вкусовщины: ВетрЫ враждебные взвейтесь над нами... - из советской песни. Многие слова могут иметь несколько допустимых(или не совсем) ударений в зависимости от контекста, смотря какое слово и какой акцент вам нужен в речи. Хотя есть формы, которые забанены, например: тортЫ и тОрты - это даже в школе учат, но многие все равно продолжают говорить "тортЫ" или "звОнят", некоторые говорят дЕньгами, вместо деньгАми, на манер начала 20 века, некоторые говорят свеклА, а не свЁкла(вплоть до появления другой буквы), твОрог и творОг и тд... есть более сложные как инженЕрия и инженерИя.

Comment: Что-то считается ошибкой, и вас могут поправить, но это больше придирки тех, кто любит придираться к другим, так как русские сами так часто "ошибаются" любо делают это намеренно, с целью придать определенную просторечную интонацию, юмор и тд фразе. что же касается свитерОв и свИтеров, я разницы не вижу в интонации, вообще не важно, какое ударение будет, смысла от этого ударения, в отличии от истории с ветрами и прочим, не прибавляется. Думаю, если диктор на телевидении в одном сюжете сделает два разных ударения в этом слове, 95% носителей языка этого не заметят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encounter the first form of the plural more commonly. However, the second form doesn't sound wrong to me as well.

Anyway, this has nothing to do with the old orthography.